# R merge in place

Tags: r, replace, merge

I would like to be able to update existing variables in a merge rather than add. Can someone help with base R commands to achieve this task? Here is an example:

```
A1 <-c("0ZERO","1ONE","2TWO","3THREE","4FOUR")
A2 <-c("5FIVE","6SIX","7SEVEN","8EIGHT","9NINE")
B <-c("1ONE","2TWO","3THREE")
C <-c("5FIVE","7SEVEN","8EIGHT")
X <-c(1.2,1.3,1.4)

master.df<-data.frame(A1,A2)
slave1.df<-data.frame(B,X)

X<-c(2.1,2.1,2.3)
slave2.df<-data.frame(C,X)
```

This produces a data frame but some NAs are present, fine.

```
master.df<-merge(master.df,slave1.df,by.x="A1",by.y="B",all.x=TRUE)
master.df
     A1     A2   X
1  0ZERO  5FIVE  NA
2   1ONE   6SIX 1.2
3   2TWO 7SEVEN 1.3
4 3THREE 8EIGHT 1.4
5  4FOUR  9NINE  NA
```

Now, where `NA`'s exist in `X` I want to then lookup `A2` in `slave2.df` to update the values in `X`. This is how I thought it might work:

```
master.df[is.na(master.df$X),]<-merge(master.df[is.na(master.df$X),],slave2.df,by.x="A2",by.y="C",all.x=TRUE)
```

> ```
> Warning messages:
>  1: In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, is.na(master.df$X), , value = list( :
>    provided 4 variables to replace 3 variables
>  2: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = c(1L, 5L)) :
>    invalid factor level, NA generated
>  3: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = c(1L, 5L)) :
>    invalid factor level, NA generated
> ```

But it doesn't. What I want is:

```
head(master.df)
     A1     A2   X
1  0ZERO  5FIVE 2.1
2   1ONE   6SIX 1.2
3   2TWO 7SEVEN 1.3
4 3THREE 8EIGHT 1.4
5  4FOUR  9NINE  NA
```

Note `NA`'s can still exist. Due to my setup I need to be able to do this is base `R` (but I could request a package install if people thought that was the best way to achieve this task). Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps `ind = is.na(master.df$X) ; master.df[ind,"X"] <- slave2.df[match(master.df[ind,"A2"],slave2.df$C),"X"]` ?

Comment: In the end I went for this solution. In reality I have many "X"'s and this looked to be the most appropriate. Worksop quick on a data frame with 1 million rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a `tidyverse` solution

```
library(tidyverse)
master.df %>% 
 left_join(slave1.df, by = c("A1" = "B")) %>% 
 left_join(slave2.df, by = c("A2" = "C")) %>% 
  mutate(X = ifelse(is.na(X.x), X.y, X.x)) %>% 
  select(1:2, X)
      A1     A2   X
1  0ZERO  5FIVE 2.1
2   1ONE   6SIX 1.2
3   2TWO 7SEVEN 1.3
4 3THREE 8EIGHT 1.4
5  4FOUR  9NINE  NA
```

In base R you can try

```
master.df[is.na(master.df$X),3] <- merge(master.df[is.na(master.df$X),],slave2.df,by.x="A2",by.y="C",all.x=TRUE)[,4]
master.df
      A1     A2   X
1  0ZERO  5FIVE 2.1
2   1ONE   6SIX 1.2
3   2TWO 7SEVEN 1.3
4 3THREE 8EIGHT 1.4
5  4FOUR  9NINE  NA
```

It is your solution with minor improvements regarding subsetting.